# How important is a character's sexuality when it come to audience appeal

Tags: marketing

I ask because I came across this comment about putting gay characters in games:

> The necessity of exposing the larger playerbase to the homosexual tendencies of two of its cast mates is never really expounded upon by ScreenRant. That’s not to mention that only a tiny percentage of people even identify as on the LGBTQ spectrum, even according to Gallup, which puts the national average at 4.5%. So why exactly would Blizzard force the majority of their straight players to have to engage with the homosexual tendencies of two of its non-straight characters?
>
> ([Source](https://www.oneangrygamer.net/2019/01/sjw-angry-that-blizzard-didnt-force-soldier-76s-gayness-onto-more-overwatch-players/75093/))

And here:

> So what better way to get back at the core gamers who dropped one-liners and zingers that have become memes of legend, than to strip away from gamers the last remaining normal character in Overwatch?
>
> Most people figured Soldier 76 would be safe. He’s a patriotic military man, a hard-fighting soldier with undying loyalty, and a code of honor. He’s the perfect representation for what the majority of gamers like to see out of a hero. And besides, you need at least one normal sized, healthy, properly muscled straight, white male with all of his limbs intact to cater to the majority of your playerbase. Right? … RIGHT?!
>
> The average male gamer typically gravitates toward a game where there’s a character who looks like he can kick butt and take names, and Soldier 76 was that guy.

....

> The last bastion for masculinity in a game that’s constantly bleeding testosterone faster than the Overwatch League bleeds viewership,
>
> ([Source](https://www.oneangrygamer.net/2019/01/overwatch-turns-the-last-normal-character-gay/74757/))

It's obvious that this guy thought that 76 was straight before this. So his outrage that his face character was revealed to be gay when there was no evidence to say otherwise beforehand is pretty sad.

Beyond this there is a point he makes that is interesting. Is a characters sexuality really that important? Yes most gamers are straight, but does that automatically mean that every game character needs to be straight? Or is this an appeal to the majority fallacy?

Comment: If the real world isn't 100% straight, why would we falsify our game worlds by making them so?

Comment: I guess this comes to the dilemma of of what your users think is correct vs what you think is correct. If most of your users were racists, would you make a game that promotes racism? In my opinion, as long as users are not forced to interact in a flirty way with a character (gay or not) it shouldn't matter what their sexuality is. Maybe the positive stance these companies take would help some users understand that gay people come in all tastes, and anyone they meet could be gay, but as long as they don't plan to flirt with them, it shouldn't matter.